# Exchanging of line coordinates

Tags: geometry

So, I have $x_0$, $y_0$ and $x_1$, $y_1$ of one line. I need to get new parallel line with an offset of first by fixed number. I have seen some formulas

Ex:
$d^2 = (x_1 - x_0)^2 + (y_1 - y_0)^2$

$y_1 - y_0 = -\frac{1}{k}(x_1 - x_0)$

but I don't know how to use them. So I need your help or advice.

Answer (score 1):

Let me know if I misunderstand the question, though I present my thoughts a little different than you suggest. We have a line, say $$\epsilon: y - y_1 = \frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1 - x_0}\cdot (x-x_1) $$
and we want to create a line $\delta$ which is parallel to $\epsilon$ with $d(\delta,\epsilon) = |k|$. Since they are  parallel, they are going to have the same slope, i.e.$ \frac{y_1 - y_0}{x_1 - x_0}$.

In order to find the equation of $\delta$ we need to find a point in $\delta$. Consider the point $M(x_1,y_1)$ on $\epsilon$ and take a point $D(a,b)$ on $\delta$ such that $d(M,D) = |k| \iff d^2 = k^2.$

Thus, we have:
$$k^2=(x_1-a)^2 + (y_1-b)^2.\tag{1}$$

Also, the line defined by the points $M(x_1,y_1)$ and $D(a,b)$ will be perpendicular to $\epsilon$, hence:
$$\frac{y_1-b}{x_1-a}\cdot \frac{y_1-y_0}{x_1-x_0} = -1.\tag{2}$$

From $(1),(2)$ we should be able to define the coordinates $a,b$.

Notice that we are going to take $2$ lines parallel to $\epsilon$.